# mnesia working with DCD/DCL

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I have blown up my ejabberd. I really cannot figure out what is broken. Anyhow, will have a look at that later. What I need is my roster. Everything should be stored in the mnesia db.

I want to extract my contacts (remember, I cannot start my ejabberd, erl is working)

How would I do this in the best way? I never worked with erlang, neither with mnesia. I suspect my roster beeing in the file roster.DCD.

Dumping the content of that file into a textfile would be enough for the moment...

Any help would be welcome :-)

With best regards

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the cause of your ejabberd problem is something other than a Mnesia database corruption, you can start an Erlang shell and read from the database directly. Run this command:

```
erl -sname ejabberd@myhost -s mnesia -mnesia dir '"/var/lib/ejabberd"'
```

Note that I am assuming you are using the typical Ejabberd configuration. Replace /var/lib/ejabberd with the right directory name.

Alternately, if you can get ejabberd to at least *start*, even if it doesn't "work" in some sense, you can simplify this further by just starting Ejabberd and then running `ejabberdctl debug`. This way you don't have to guess the correct node name.

Anyway, once you've got your Erlang shell open, run this command:

```
mnesia:dump_to_textfile("my_ejabberd.txt").
```

and hit Ctrl+C twice to exit, and you should be all set.

Comment: Hey,thx for your help. Looks like I have another problem here, when I do what you suggest I get some crash: (ejabberd@localhost)1> mnesia:dump_to_textfile("my_ejabberd.txt").
=ERROR REPORT==== 20-Jun-2011::16:42:08 ===
Mnesia(ejabberd@localhost): ** ERROR ** (core dumped to file: "/root/MnesiaCore.ejabberd@localhost_1308_580928_388884")
 ** FATAL ** mnesia_tm crashed: {aborted,{badarg,caps_features,majority}} state: [<0.45.0>]
Any idea what I could try?

Comment: Oh dear, I'm not sure what to do in that case. You might want to try asking the erlang-questions email list.